# JQuery Link Dependencies - Parent, Child

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, parent-child, parent

I am very new to Javascript and JQuery and I am faced with the following:

We are building a task tree to help guide users for coursework based on their interests.

For each course path there will be a series of links such as:

**HTML**

```
<a href="" id="" math="0" ela="0" social="0" science="0" self="0" active="1">Link 0</a>
        <br />
<a class="inactive" id="" ela="2" social="1" science="1" math="1" active="0" self="1" parent="0" >Link 1</a>  <a class="inactive" id="" ela="4" social="2" science="2" math="2" active="0" parent="0" self="2">Link 2</a>
    <br />
<a  class="inactive" id="" ela="3" social="3" science="3" math="3" active="0" parent="1,2" self="3" >Link 3</a> <a  class="inactive"  id="" ela="4" social="4" science="4" math="4" active="0" parent="1,2" self="4">Link 4</a> <a  class="inactive"  id="" ela="5" social="5" science="5" math="5" active="0"  parent="1,2" self="5">Link 5</a>
        <br />
<a  class="inactive" id="" ela="6" social="6" science="6" math="6" active="0" parent="3,4,5" >Link 6</a> <a  class="inactive"  id="" ela="7" social="7" science="7" math="7" active="0" parent="3,4,5">Link 7</a> <a  class="inactive"  id="" ela="8" social="8" science="8" math="8" active="0"  parent="3,4,5" >Link 8</a> <a  class="inactive"  id="" ela="9" social="9" science="9" math="9" active="0"  parent="3,4,5" >Link 9</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    self = $(this).attr("self");

    $("a[parent*="+self+"]").attr("active", 1).attr("href", "").removeClass("inactive");
});
```

My challenge is setting up dependencies and making child links clickable only after the parent(s) have been successfully acknowledged (presumably by clicking).  The above works for either/or parents having been clicked but I am looking a means where the all parents must be clicked before the resulting child links are available to be completed.  E.g. (Links 3, 4 and 5 would only be available after both 1 and 2 had been clicked. right now 3, 4, 5 are available if either 2 OR 3 have been clicked.)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jtkisd/BEj9y/7/)**

Comment: JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jtkisd/BEj9y/7/

Comment: You should use `data-*` attributes instead.